# If $r$ (mod $p$) is a primitive root, then $r+p$ is also a primitive root mod p

Tags: elementary-number-theory, primitive-roots

I've struggled with this problem for a while...I tried to figure it out using a reduced residue system's theorem but I honestly have no idea how to work with the given hypothesis.

Comment: $r\equiv r+p\pmod{p}.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$r$ (mod $p$) is a primitive root.

This means that there is a $k$ with $r^k = a$ mod $p$ for all $a$ coprime to $p$.

$(r+p)^k = r^k$ mod $p$

which means that l exists such as $l = k$ with $(r+p)^l = a$ mod $p$ for all $a$ coprime to $p$.

Therefore $(r+p)$ is a promitive root as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I'm not sure why  $r^{k}=a$ mod $p$ for all $a$ coprime to $p$.

Comment: Isn't that the definition of a primitive root? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n

Comment: Ohh thanks! The book I'm currently using states it a bit different, but now I understand that it is (and must be) basically the same... I guess I haven't seen it that way

Comment: @Sponge **Key Idea:** *all* of the (modular) definitions of "$r$ is a primitive root $\!\bmod{\!p}$" are statements concerning powers $\, r^n\pmod{\! p}.\,$ Replacing $\,r\,$ by $\,r_1 \equiv r\pmod{\!p}\,$ doesn't alter the truth of such statements since $\,r_1\equiv r\Rightarrow\ r_1^n\equiv r^n\pmod{\!p}\,$ by the [Congruence Power Rule](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242). In particular this is true for your $\, r_1 = r + p\ \ $

Comment: Thanks, @BillDubuque that's very useful!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: By the binomial theorem, all the terms of $(r+p)^k$ except the first have a factor of $p$.  Thus each of them is zero $\bmod p$.

Or even more elegantly, by *the congruence power rule* $(r+p)^k=r^k$.  See @BillDubuque's comment below.

Comment: Said comment does *not* imply that. Rather, it is implied by the  [Congruence Power Rule](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242) (or equivalent).

Comment: Right @BillDubuque.  I will correct it.

Comment: Now elaborated in my comment on the other answer.

Comment: @BillDubuque Indeed, I gave said comment too much credit.